Understanding when laplacian eigen-coordinates on a 2-torus to $\mathbb{R}^3$ is an immersion
So I am trying to understand when the laplacian eigenfunctions from a torus–when graphed against each other–form a smooth immersion. We take the laplacian operator $L=-\partial_{x_1}-\partial_{x_2}$ on the torus. Some computation shows that the general form of the eigen-functions are
$$A\sin(c_1x_1+c_2x_2)+B\cos(c_1x_1+c_2x_2)$$
where if $v_1,v_2$ are the interior and exterior circumferences , we have that  $c_1v_1+c_2v_2=2\pi k$ for $k\in \mathbb Z$.
For 3 such functions $f_1,f_2,f_3$ with 'small' eigenvalues, I am trying to understand the image of the map $F(x_1,x_2):=(f_1(x_1,x_2), f_2(x_1,x_2) ,f_3(x_1,x_2))$. For this aim, I would like to understand when it is possible for for $F$ to be a smooth immersion (or even embedding). Computing the differential by hand becomes very complicated very quickly. Is there a higher level approach to this type of problem? Any direction would be helpful. The context  is that I am in an REU and trying to better understand the behavior of the objects I am working with. Thank you!
